# Is starter motor running if I hold the ignition switch at the START position?

Tags: automotive-engineering

Suppose that the engine cranking has been successful but I  keep holding the ignition switch at the START position instead of releasing the switch to go at the RUN position. Does this mean that the starter motor is still spinning or has it somehow disengaged (probably through the starter solenoid ) from the battery?

Comment: see similar question ; https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/67658/10976

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs migrating to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair

Comment: Yes it is a similar question but this one has not been answered. What happens to the starter motor if I don' release the key?

Comment: I deleted the other question as this one is more to to the point I would like to point at.

Comment: This question is too open-ended.  For *most* cars the answer is yes, but any car that thinks its smarter than you might be engineered to disengage the starter automatically when the engine starts.  This is more likely in modern cars with computers, but it could be easily (if not cheaply or reliably) done with 1912 technology.

Comment: There is probably a **lot** of cars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flywheel will accelerate faster than the starter motor and the ring gear will accelerate the starter dog since there is a bendix drive or over-run clutch to allow this to happen so the starter motor itself will not overspeed. This does create noise which most notice...

Comment: I know about the protection of the starter motor if the engine has cranked. The question is : will the starter motor keep drawing current ( even a very tiny one because of no load at the driveshaft)?

Comment: That is now a different question. the starter will still draw current but much less as it does not need to develop the power to turn the engine.

Comment: If it is drawing current then it is spinning (even at no load or a very tiny one). So I think it is not a different question. Thank you anyway.

Comment: As I have answered both your questions, consider voting or accepting the answer with the check mark.